# Use a specific locale for Seam logger

Tags: logging, internationalization, seam

The Seam logger uses, deep down, Java’s `MessageFormat` class to format eg. numbers. The locale used for this comes from the `org.jboss.seam.core.locale`, if I interpret the code correctly. However, I do not know how to proceed from there. I want the logger to use the English locale only (any English locale would be fine) because all our logging is in English. The system or the user may well have another locale, but this should not influence logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that elegant because you have to duplicate almost all the code except one line, but you can override the built-in implementation of Interpolator component.

```
/**
 * Interpolates EL expressions in Strings
 * 
 * @author Gavin King
 */
@BypassInterceptors
@Scope(STATELESS)
@Name("org.jboss.seam.core.interpolator")
@Install(precedence=APPLICATION)
public class Interpolator extends org.jboss.seam.core.Interpolator  
{

    private static final LogProvider log = Logging.getLogProvider(Interpolator.class);


    /**
     * Replace all EL expressions in the form #{...} with their evaluated
     * values.
     * 
     * @param string a template
     * @return the interpolated string
     */
    @Override
    public String interpolate(String string, Object... params) 
    {
        if (params == null) {
            params = new Object[0];
        }

        if (params.length>10) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("more than 10 parameters");
        }

        if (string.indexOf('#')>=0 || string.indexOf('{')>=0) {
            string = interpolateExpressions(string, params);
        }

        return string;
    }

    private String interpolateExpressions(String string, Object... params)
    {
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(string, "#{}", true);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(string.length());
        try {
            while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String tok = tokens.nextToken();

                if ("#".equals(tok) && tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String nextTok = tokens.nextToken();

                    while (nextTok.equals("#") && tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        builder.append(tok);
                        nextTok = tokens.nextToken();
                    }

                    if ("{".equals(nextTok)) {
                        String expression = "#{" + tokens.nextToken() + "}";
                        try {
                            Object value = Expressions.instance().createValueExpression(expression).getValue();
                            if (value!=null) builder.append(value);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            log.debug("exception interpolating string: " + string, e);
                        }
                        tokens.nextToken(); // the trailing "}"

                    } else if (nextTok.equals("#"))  {
                        // could be trailing # 
                        builder.append("#");

                    } else {
                        int index;
                        try {
                            index = Integer.parseInt(nextTok.substring(0, 1));
                            if (index>=params.length) {
                                //log.warn("parameter index out of bounds: " + index + " in: " + string);
                                builder.append("#").append(nextTok);
                            } else {
                                builder.append(params[index]).append(nextTok.substring(1));
                            }
                        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                            builder.append("#").append(nextTok);
                        }
                    }
                } else if ("{".equals(tok)) {
                    StringBuilder expr = new StringBuilder();

                    expr.append(tok);
                    int level = 1;

                    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        String nextTok = tokens.nextToken();
                        expr.append(nextTok);

                        if (nextTok.equals("{")) {
                            ++level;
                        } else if (nextTok.equals("}")) {
                            if (--level == 0) {
                                try {
                                    if (params.length == 0)
                                    {
                                        builder.append(expr.toString());
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //String value = new MessageFormat(expr.toString(), Locale.instance()).format(params);
                                        // always use Locale.ENGLISH
                                        String value = new MessageFormat(expr.toString(), Locale.ENGLISH).format(params);
                                        builder.append(value);

                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // if it is a bad message, use the expression itself
                                    builder.append(expr);                             
                                }
                                expr = null;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } 

                    if (expr != null) {
                        builder.append(expr);
                    }
                } else {
                    builder.append(tok);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug("exception interpolating string: " + string, e);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Inelegant indeed, but since no one else has a better solution, this is it. Note, however, that the code you posted will not work, as the class must be of compatible type – just extend the original seam Interpolator and it will work. Thank you!

Comment: Good point. I edited the code in order to extend the original Interpolator.